# Float distance for 80 bit long double

Tags: c++, floating-point, distance

For `float`, `double`, and `__float128`, we have the following code which computes the number of representables between them:

```cpp
int32_t float_distance(float x, float y) {
    static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int32_t), "float is incorrect size.");
    int32_t xi = *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&x);
    int32_t yi = *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(&y);
    return yi - xi;
}

int64_t float_distance(double x, double y) {
    static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(int64_t), "double is incorrect size.");
    int64_t xi = *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&x);
    int64_t yi = *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&y);
    return yi - xi;
}


__int128_t float_distance(__float128 x, __float128 y) {
    static_assert(sizeof(__float128) == sizeof(__int128_t), "quad is incorrect size.");
    __int128_t xi = *reinterpret_cast<__int128_t*>(&x);
    __int128_t yi = *reinterpret_cast<__int128_t*>(&y);
    return yi - xi;
}
```

(This code works for x,y > 0, for legibility we aren't dealing with the general case.)

There is no `int80_t`, so what is the analogous code for `long double`? Out of desperation, I tried both `__int128_t` and `__int64_t` return types, but no joy.

Edit: It seems like this is not a well-known property of IEEE-754 floating point numbers. [Here's](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/stupid-float-tricks-2/) a good read for those who are wondering why this works.

Comment: This violates the strict aliasing rule; you should use `memcpy` or `bit_cast` instead. You could just copy to the lower 80 bits of a 128-bit int if that's what you want. (And be prepared for systems whose long double is not 80 bits...)

Comment: ...and requires a fairly loose definition of "between" :)

Comment: @tadman: it's not garbage at all. It does exactly what the question says: "computes the number of representables between" (in case of IEEE-754, at least).

Comment: Maybe you can zero an `__int128_t`, and memcpy the long double into the lowest 10 bytes. And take care of the highest mantissa bit (if we're talking about x87).

Comment: @M.M: std::bit_cast looks good, but I'd prefer to not use C++20. The `memcpy` documentation says that the array should not overlap: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

Comment: As it stands, the assembly generated by this code is basically perfect: a move from an `xmm` register into an integer register with the correct width depending on the type.

Comment: @user14717 there is no overlapping in this case, you memcpy from the argument to the local object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the properties of the floating-point representation provided in the `numeric_limits` template of the `<numeric>` header and routines in `<cmath>`. No examination of the bits representing the values is required. Here is sample code in C++.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>

#include <numeric>


/*  Return the signed distance from 0 to x, measuring distance as one unit per
    number representable in FPType.  x must be a finite number.
*/
template<typename FPType> intmax_t ToOrdinal(FPType x)
{
    static const int
        Radix             = std::numeric_limits<FPType>::radix,
        SignificandDigits = std::numeric_limits<FPType>::digits,
        MinimumExponent   = std::numeric_limits<FPType>::min_exponent;

    //  Number of normal representable numbers for each exponent.
    static const intmax_t
        NumbersPerExponent = scalbn(Radix-1, SignificandDigits-1);

    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<FPType>::has_denorm == std::denorm_present,
        "This code presumes floating-point type has subnormal numbers.");

    if (x == 0)
        return 0;

    //  Separate the sign.
    int sign = std::signbit(x) ? -1 : +1;
    x = std::fabs(x);

    //  Separate the significand and exponent.
    int exponent = std::ilogb(x)+1;
    FPType fraction = std::scalbn(x, -exponent);

    if (exponent < MinimumExponent)
    {
        //  For subnormal x, adjust to its subnormal representation.
        fraction = std::scalbn(fraction, exponent - MinimumExponent);
        exponent = MinimumExponent;
    }

    /*  Start with the number of representable numbers in preceding normal
        exponent ranges.
    */
    intmax_t count = (exponent - MinimumExponent) * NumbersPerExponent;

    /*  For subnormal numbers, fraction * radix ** SignificandDigits is the
        number of representable numbers from 0 to x.  For normal numbers,
        (fraction-1) * radix ** SignificandDigits is the number of
        representable numbers from the start of x's exponent range to x, and
        1 * radix ** SignificandDigits is the number of representable subnormal
        numbers (which we have not added into count yet).  So, in either case,
        adding fraction * radix ** SignificandDigits is the desired amount to
        add to count.
    */
    count += (intmax_t) std::scalbn(fraction, SignificandDigits);

    return sign * count;
}


/*  Return the number of representable numbers from x to y, including one
    endpoint.
*/
template<typename FPType> intmax_t Distance(FPType y, FPType x)
{
    return ToOrdinal(y) - ToOrdinal(x);
}


#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>


template<typename FPType> static void Try(FPType x)
{
    std::cout << x << " -> " << ToOrdinal(x) << ".\n";
}


int main(void)
{
    Try(0.f);
    Try(0x1p-149f);
    Try(0x1p-127f);
    Try(0x1p-126f);
    Try(0x1p-126f + 0x1p-149f);
    Try(1.f);
    Try(1.5f);
    Try(0.l);
    Try(1.l);
    Try(1.5l);

    //  Test from 3 steps below 4 to 5 steps above 4.
    float x = 4, y = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        x = std::nexttowardf(x, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        y = std::nexttowardf(y, INFINITY);
    std::cout << "There are " << Distance(y, x) << std::setprecision(8)
        << " representable numbers from " << x << " to " << y << ".\n";

}
```

Comment: I really like the explicit static assert on the presence of denorms; I would've forgotten entirely about that.

Comment: @user14717: Thanks. When I wrote this, I was also tempted to support implementations without subnormals. All that is necessary is to subtract one from `fraction` before scaling it by `SignificandDigits`.

Comment: I think a small criticism of this answer is that the others examples compile down to moves from floating point registers to integer registers, and hence are blazing fast, whereas this does a large number of manipulations that exploit generic structure of any floating point format. Still, great answer.